# (psycopg2.errors.InvalidForeignKey) there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "shop_item_skus"

Tags: postgresql, psql

How can I fix this? The code:

`  **tablename** = "shop_sku_prices"
id = Column( Integer, primary_key=True )
sku_id = Column( Integer, ForeignKey("shop_item_skus.id"), nullable=False, primary_key=True )
currency = Column( String(5), nullable=False )
unit_price = Column( Integer, nullable=False )

```
def __init__(self, sku_id, currency, unit_price):
    self.sku_id = sku_id
    self.currency = currency
    self.unit_price = unit_price`
```

`item_sku_id = Column( Integer, ForeignKey( "shop_item_skus.id" ), nullable=False ) quantity = Column( Integer, nullable=False ) unit_price = Column( Integer, nullable=False ) total_price = Column( Integer, nullable=False )`

`sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidForeignKey) there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "shop_item_skus" [SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE shop_sku_prices (\n\tid INTEGER NOT NULL, \n\tsku_id INTEGER NOT NULL, \n\tcurrency VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, \n\tunit_price INTEGER NOT NULL, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (id, sku_id), \n\tFOREIGN KEY(sku_id) REFERENCES shop_item_skus (id)\n)\n\n'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)`

`python3 create_postgresql_database.py
/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py:873: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1236, in _execute_context
cursor, statement, parameters, context
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 536, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.InvalidForeignKey: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "shop_item_skus"

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "create_postgresql_database.py", line 903, in 
db.create_all()
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py", line 1094, in create_all
self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py", line 1086, in _execute_for_all_tables
op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 4200, in create_all
ddl.SchemaGenerator, self, checkfirst=checkfirst, tables=tables
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2011, in _run_visitor
conn._run_visitor(visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1599, in _run_visitor
visitorcallable(self.dialect, self, **kwargs).traverse_single(element)
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 130, in traverse_single
return meth(obj, **kw)
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 779, in visit_metadata
_is_metadata_operation=True,
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 130, in traverse_single
return meth(obj, **kw)
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 824, in visit_table
include_foreign_key_constraints,
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 980, in execute
return meth(self, multiparams, params)
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 72, in _execute_on_connection
return connection._execute_ddl(self, multiparams, params)
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1042, in _execute_ddl
compiled,
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1240, in _execute_context
e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1458, in _handle_dbapi_exception
util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 296, in raise_from_cause
reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 276, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1236, in _execute_context
cursor, statement, parameters, context
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 536, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidForeignKey) there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "shop_item_skus"
[SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE shop_sku_prices (\n\tid INTEGER NOT NULL, \n\tsku_id INTEGER NOT NULL, \n\tcurrency VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, \n\tunit_price INTEGER NOT NULL, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (id, sku_id), \n\tFOREIGN KEY(sku_id) REFERENCES shop_item_skus (id)\n)\n\n'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)`

Nothing yet but unable to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states there is no matching `UNIQUE` constraint in the table that is referenced by the foreign key constraint. So you have to create such a `UNIQUE` constraint.

The foreign key seems to reference the table `shop_item_skus` and within it the column `id`. Given the name `id` I would expect that field not only to be unique but also `NOT NULL` so it could even be a primary key. I suspect an oversight or an issue with the underlying database design.